# BDD SpecFlow Scenarios

Tags: c#, .net, testing, bdd, specflow

Today I started studying BDD using SpecFlow + Selenium and I found several examples that only showing **1 return**.

How do I write a  scenario that returns **more than one item**. For example:

```
Given a name "test"
I click on the SEARCH button
```

**Then the result will be equal to the table below:**

```
name | last name
test | fulano
test | siclano
```

**In this case,  How do I write the THEN?, accepting return the 2 rows of the table showed?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scenario:

```
Given a name "test"
When I click on the SEARCH button
Then the result will be 
| name | last name
| test | fulano
| test | siclano
```

code:

```
[Then("The result will be")]
public void ThenTheResultWillBe(Table table)
{
    //check that the result contains all the values in the table
}
```